# Pf rules configuration

Tags: firewalls

Do these rules appear to be an adequate start?

```
_interface="en1"

_linode="66.228.57.75" #lish-atlanta.linode.com 
_ssh=" { 74.207.224.182 66.175.210.225 } "

set block-policy drop
set skip on lo0

set state-policy if-bound
set loginterface $_interface
set require-order yes

scrub out 
scrub  in 

antispoof quick for { vboxnet0 lo0  $_interface }

block in  log
block out log

pass out quick on vboxnet0 proto { tcp udp } to 192.168.56.101 port { 22 }

pass in quick on $_interface proto { udp } to port { 68 }

#pass out quick on $_interface proto { tcp udp } to any
pass out quick  on $_interface proto {     udp } to any port { 53 67   }
pass out quick  on $_interface proto { tcp udp } to any port { 80 443  }

pass out quick on $_interface proto tcp to $_linode port 22
pass out quick on $_interface proto tcp to $_ssh    port 47
```

Can any one give me more suggestions as to a good basic config?